# How can I debug through two or more concerrent requests using IIS 7.5 and VS2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, iis-7.5

I have tried setting in iis under the asp section:
Client Side Debugging = false
Server Side Debugging = false

and in my web.config `<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">`

Now this is all turning debug off which I though would allow concurrent requests but it still doesnt. If one request is still processing, the other request just queues untill it finishes.

Ideally I want to be able to step through each request at the same time.
Like I can do with a console app and creating threads!

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of requests? Do you use session or ViewState?

Comment: I use session and viewstate but I can disable session and still perform the tests I need to do.